# Error response from AX 2012 AIF Services "Could not convert some or all identity references"

Tags: web-services, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, aif

I'm receiving this error message (self translated from spanish) ...

> "Could not convert some or all identity references"

May be (see comments)

> Some or all identity references could not be translated

... when invoking my own custom services published in AX 2012. It's a test service, very simple with only one public method only for testing connectivity and security.

Service was working fine and started giving this message after a database backup recover into the development application to test with real data.

I suspect some kind of security problem but I'm unable to find it. Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: The English translation of the error is probably "Some or all identity references could not be translated"

Comment: What type of port are you using? Did you recreate the port? Does it have security option configured, eg "Restrict users" or "Trusted intermediate"? This might refer to account from an other active directory.

Comment: Yes this may be the translation too. It's a NetTcp port deployed by default, without any further security setup. I tried same user (into the same AD) running the AOS and executing the app that consumes the service and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find the problem. When you instance the `CallContext` object you need to specify the domain in the `LogonAsUser` member. If only user specified you get the error message of the original question. This way it works:

```
CallContext context = new CallContext();
context.Company = "COMPANYCODE";
context.Language = "es";
context.LogonAsUser = @"DOMAIN\USER";  // Domain is important!
```

Thanks!